# IServiceCollection - Dependency Injection? Available Where?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am learning ASP.NET core though a pluralsite video. The fellow in the video tells me I can add a "service" as a singleton or as a transient, by registering it in Startup.ConfigureServices.

```
public class Startup {

    public Startup() {
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

        // Register the Greeter as an IGreeter and have the ASP.NET framework register it to be available to anyone who wants an IGreeter
        // Dependency injection?
        services.AddSingleton<IGreeter, Greeter>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IGreeter greeter) {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.Run(async (context) => {
            var greeting = greeter.GetGreeting();
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(greeting);
        });
    }
}
```

He wasn't very clear about who is instantiating it, what its life time is, and where it is available. Can someone fill in those details for me?

Is this doing what I would have done with a dependency injection framework like Autofac, but ASP.NET Core has it built in? Or is this different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> who is instantiating it, what its lifetime is, and where it is
>   available.

The framework will instantiate the service with the lifetime you specified during registering it in your DI-Container. All your registered services are available in the projects that have referenced from the main project which contains your DI-Container.

> Is this doing what I would have done with a dependency injection
>   framework like Autofac, but ASP.NET Core has it built in? Or is this
>   different?

Everything is the same as other DI Containers like `AutoFac`. DI is done using ASP.NET Core's built-in DI Container called **[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2)**